Issue faced on the format of the received HL7message.I am receiving the HL7 message with MSH and EVN segments in a single line
I’m facing issue in the format of the HL7message received. I have configured , formatted the segments and gave the template in the outbound. I am able to receive the encoded message but I am receiving the HL7 message  with MSH and EVN segments in a single line .In Hl7 message the segments MSH and EVN must be one below the other.
Here’s what I’ve received as encoded message
HL7message|MSH|^~&|Roseline||||20240808054200| |ADT^A04eP03|52b55066-d287-4780-be4f-1c8dd5fb4d39|P|2.4EVN|P03|20151114
Can someone please guide me on what I might be missing or suggest any troubleshooting steps?
Thank you in advance for your help!

HL7 specifies a segment delimiter of \r, which is not a typical newline (\n or \r\n).  Presumably the sending system is not generating the appropriate segment delimiter, or the Mirth channel is configured for a non-standard segment delimiter.

The MSH.2 - Encoding Characters only have 3 values '^~&' where as there should be 4, usually '^~&'. i.e. |MSH|^~&|...
It sounds like you're generating the HL7 yourself, in which case you can just add the '\ and it should work. If it is already there check that there's not preprocessing that's removing this.
